# Ruby one liner for method undefined or nil

Tags: ruby

I was curious whether there is a shorter way to check whether a method is defined on an object, and if it is, check whether it is nil or not. I've tried:

```
if !obj.respond_to?(:meth) || obj.meth.nil?
```

But it looks very long and ugly.

Comment: Are you dealing with some objectified hashes or something?

Comment: No, I am dealing with a plain object which may/may not have `:meth` defined.

Comment: You got bit by the precedence mite. Your expression is equivalent to: `if !obj.respond_to? :meth`. That's because `:meth || obj.meth.nil?` is evaluated first, and will always return `:meth`.  Suppose we have `class String; def s; nil; end; end; obj = 'cat'`. Then `!obj.respond_to? :meth || obj.meth.nil? #=> false`, whereas `!(obj.respond_to? :meth) || obj.meth.nil? #=> true`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I've added the correct paranthesis, just that I've forgot to put them in the question.

Comment: That's understandable, but I'll leave my comment for it's educational value.

Comment: I think if `!(obj.respond_to?(:meth) && obj.meth != nil)` reads better, but others may disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty but concise:

```
unless (obj.meth rescue nil)
  ...
end
```

If sending `meth` to `obj` fails (e.g. because the method is missing), the expression takes the value `nil`.

Of course this hides all kinds of errors in `meth`.

Comment: +5 for inventiveness and +5 for honesty.

Comment: Going with this solution, as it's both clever and closest to my one-liner I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433697/ruby-one-liner-for-method-undefined-or-nil/29433827#29433827) suggested, [`try` from ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb) is exactly what you want. Using `try`, your code would read like this:

```
if obj.try(:meth).nil?
  # obj either lacks :meth or has :meth that returns nil
end
```

Very concise and readable, I think.

If you aren't using ActiveSupport, you can quickly reimplement a simple version `try` yourself:

```
class Object
  def try(method, *args)
    public_send(method, *args) if respond_to?(method)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're in rails, you can use `.try`

```
[1] pry(main)> h = {}
=> {}
[2] pry(main)> h.try(:foo)
=> nil
```

Comment: Good information, but irrelevant without Rails tag.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: maybe he forgot to tag with rails. It happens.

Comment: It's never happened to me. Of course, I don't know Rails.

Answer (score 2):

In part to make it read well, I'd do it this way:

```
def has_method?(obj, method)
  obj.methods.include?(method)
end

has_method?(2, :+)            #=> true
has_method?('cat', :upcase)   #=> true
has_method?('cat', :group_by) #=> false
has_method?(Array, :new)      #=> true
```

So it would be:

```
!has_method?(obj, :meth) ||  obj.meth.nil?
```

or just:

```
!obj.methods.include?(:meth) || obj.meth.nil?
```

or:

```
!(obj.methods.include?(:meth) && obj.meth != nil)
```

Comment: It looks alright, but it's the same length as my proposal.

Comment: But this isn't [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9359/shortest-program-that-throws-stackoverflow-error). Consider only readability, which is only loosely correlated with length. That's why I prefer, for example, `obj.meth != nil` to `!object.nil?`. I am (almost) indifferent, however, between `methods.include?` and `respond_to?`; I just wanted to provide another option.

Comment: I expect `respond_to?` would be faster, if that's important.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `defined?` keyword.

```
irb(main):066:0> obj = "test" # in this case obj is a string
=> "test"
irb(main):067:0> defined? obj.split
=> "method"
irb(main):068:0> defined? obj.not_a_func
=> nil
```

[defined?](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F)

> defined? expression tests whether or not expression refers to anything recognizable (literal object, local variable that has been initialized, ***method name visible from the current scope***, etc.). **The return value is nil if the expression cannot be resolved**.

Comment: He needs to call it too :)

Comment: Also `defined?` is a keyword, not a method

Comment: thanks @SergioTulentsev, updated the answer to keyword

Comment: defined? won't tell you if the result of calling the method is nil though and won't work for methods that are implemented or defined via method_missinf

Comment: As an illustration of @FrederickCheung's first point, consider `Kernel.puts #=> nil`. To answer the OP's question, you are proposing to return: `!(defined? Kernel.puts) #=> false`, yet `!(Kernel.respond_to? :puts) || Kernel.puts.nil? #=> true`.